# Beamer theme metropolis does not allow different font size for fullcite

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, biber, beamer-metropolis

Consider this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foobar,
author={Bar, Foo},
title={Yadda yadda},
journal={Journal of whatever},
year=2023,
volume=1}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \fullcite{foobar}

    {\scriptsize\fullcite{foobar}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It works correctly: the second line is presented in a smaller font than the first line.
However, adding `\usetheme{metropolis}` causes the font on both lines to have the same size (the size of the larger one).

I cannot figure out what in the metropolis theme code is causing this behaviour and how to get this right.

(Scriptsize in general works with metropolis, just not in conjunction with fullcite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between normal themes and metropolis is caused by metropolis explicitly setting normal size for various bibliography fonts.

As a quick hack you can revert this by using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foobar,
author={Bar, Foo},
title={Yadda yadda},
journal={Journal of whatever},
year=2023,
volume=1}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry title}{size=}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry author}{size=}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry location}{size=}
\setbeamerfont{bibliography entry note}{size=}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \fullcite{foobar}

    {\scriptsize\fullcite{foobar}}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is correct! Although I cannot imagine why metropolis would want to mess with citation font styles... :-)

Comment: @AlbertoSantini Metropolis messes with everything :) \begin{rant}... and does not even merge any patches which would ensure that it stays compilable with current latex versions, so beamer has to jump through a lot of loops to patch patches of patches just to keep it from dying\end{rant}